# NAs produced by integer overflow + R on linux

Tags: r

I'm running an R script on UNIX based system , the script contain multiplication of large numbers , so the results where NAs by integer overflow , but when i run the same script on windows , this problem does not appears.

but i should keep the script working the whole night on the Desktop(which is Unix).

is there any solution for this problem?

thanks

```
for(ol in seq(1,nrow(yi),by=25))
    {
    for(oh in seq(1,nrow(yi),by=25))
 {

        A=(N*(ol^2)) + ((N*(N+1)*(2*N+1))/6) -(2*ol*((N*N+1)/2)) + (2*N*ol*(N-oh+1)) + ((N-oh+1)*N^2) + (2*N*(oh-N-1)*(oh+N))


}
}

    with :
N=16569 = nrow(yi)
```

but first round is not being calculated on unix.

Comment: Some sample code illustrating the problem would be nice. You'll have to give the specifications for both systems as well: Are they 32bit, 64bit, which Windows and Linux are we talking about, ...

Comment: @Joris Meys  : the windows is windows 7 64 bit , and the linux is fedora 32 bit.

Comment: @weblover : can you give us two numbers that -as integer- multiplied on the UNIX give an overflow, but not on Windows? I fail to find some, but we run debian 64bit on our server.

Comment: @Joris Meys : the resulted value is something like this : -30598395869593930593 (on windows) but on unix it's not like this , it's NAs

Comment: @weblover : rather strange, as I cannot store that number as an integer in R on windows, neither in the 32bit nor in the 64bit version. I get `NA` in both cases. Even more, if I store it as double and ask format(x,scientific=FALSE), I get another number.

Comment: this number will then be divided and ... to get a small number , on windows its working .

Comment: @weblover : now that might be crucial information. Please provide us with some sample code that runs on windows and doesn't on Linux. Like this it's impossible to say how this comes about, and what you can do about it.

Comment: @JorisMeys this could depend on the version of R you are using. 2.x still uses 32-bit vectors, while 3.x finally makes use of 64-bit architecture. This, however won't help in the case of weblover, since he has a 32-bit UNIX system.

Comment: 3.something didn't exist back in 2011... ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Can you cast your integers to floating-point numbers in order to use floating-point math for the computations?

For example:

```
> x=as.integer(1000000)
> x*x
[1] NA
Warning message:
In x * x : NAs produced by integer overflow
> x=as.numeric(1000000)
> x*x
[1] 1e+12
```

As an aside, it is not entirely clear why the warning would appear in one environment but not the other. I first thought that 32-bit and 64-bit builds of R might be using 32-bit and 64-bit integers respectively, but that [doesn't appear to be the case](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Choosing-between-32_002d-and-64_002dbit-builds). Are both your environments configured identically in terms of how warnings are displayed?

Comment: i don't know how the environments are configured , but the option that you suggested change anything in the values ?? because i need accurate values at the end of the calculation.

Comment: @weblover: Floating-point math has the potential of giving you approximate results where integer math is exact. If I were you, I'd try to figure out the exact cause of the integer overflow, and take it from there.

Comment: i kni=ow exactly where is it , but i can't take it out , it's inside the mathematical calculations

Comment: @weblover : if it needs to be exact, remember that x*y = exp(log(x)+log(y)). Working with log values can give you more accuracy.

Answer (score 5):

As the other answers have pointed out, there is something a bit non-reproducible/strange about your results so far. Nevertheless, if you really must do exact calculations on large integers, you probably need an interface between R and some other system.

Some of your choices are:

- the `gmp` package (see [this page](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_integers_%28included%29) and scroll down to R
- an interface to the `bc` calculator [on googlecode](http://code.google.com/p/r-bc/)
- there is a [high precision arithmetic](http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=misc%3ar_accuracy%3ahigh_precision_arithmetic) page on the R wiki which compares interfaces to Yacas, bc, and MPFR/GMP
- there is a limited interface to the PARI/GP package in the `elliptical` package, but this is probably (much) less immediately useful than the preceding three choices

  Most Unix or Cygwin systems should have bc installed already. GMP and Yacas are easy to install on modern Linux systems ...

Here's an extended example, with a function that can choose among numeric, integer, or `bigz` computation.

```
f1 <- function(ol=1L,oh=1L,N=16569L,type=c("num","int","bigz")) {
  type <- match.arg(type)
  ## convert all values to appropriate type
  if (type=="int") {
    ol <- as.integer(ol)
    oh <- as.integer(oh)
    N <- as.integer(N)
    one <- 1L
    two <- 2L
    six <- 6L
    cc <- as.integer
  } else if (type=="bigz") {
    one <- as.bigz(1)
    two <- as.bigz(2)
    six <- as.bigz(6)
    N <- as.bigz(N)
    ol <- as.bigz(ol)
    oh <- as.bigz(oh)
    cc <- as.bigz
  } else {
    one <- 1
    two <- 2
    six <- 6
    N <- as.numeric(N)
    oh <- as.numeric(oh)
    ol <- as.numeric(ol)
    cc <- as.numeric
  }
  ## if using bigz mode, the ratio needs to be converted back to bigz;
  ## defining cc() as above seemed to be the most transparent way to do it
  N*ol^two + cc(N*(N+one)*(two*N+one)/six) -
    ol*(N*N+one) + two*N*ol*(N-oh+one) +
      (N-oh+one)*N^two + two*N*(oh-N-one)*(oh+N)
}
```

I removed a lot of unnecessary parentheses, which actually made it harder to see what was going on. It is indeed true that for the (1,1) case the final result is not bigger than `.Machine$integer.max` but some of the intermediate steps are ... (for the (1,1) case this actually reduces to $$-1/6*(N+2)*(4*N^2-5*N+3)$$ ...)

```
f1()  ##  -3.032615e+12
f1() > .Machine$integer.max  ## FALSE
N <- 16569L
N*(N+1)*(2*N+1) > .Machine$integer.max   ## TRUE
N*(N+1L)*(2L*N+1L)  ## integer overflow (NA)
f1(type="int")      ## integer overflow
f1(type="bigz")     ##  "-3032615078557"
print(f1(),digits=20)  ##  -3032615078557: no actual loss of precision in this case
```

PS: you have a `(N*N+1)` term in your equation.  Should that really be `N*(N+1)`, or did you really mean `N^2+1`?

Answer (score 3):

Given your comments, I guess that you seriously misunderstand the "correctness" of numbers in R. You say the outcome you get on Windows is something like `-30598395869593930593`. Now, on both 32bit and 64bit that precision is even not possible using a double, let alone using an integer :

```
> x <- -30598395869593930593
> format(x,scientific=F)
[1] "-30598395869593931776"
> all.equal(x,as.numeric(format(x,scientific=F)))
[1] TRUE
> as.integer(x)
[1] NA
```

You have 16 digits you can trust, all the rest is bollocks. Then again, an accuracy of 16 digits is already pretty strong. Most measurement tools don't even come close to that.

Comment: @Joris Meys : there is no solution to handle this amount of digits ??

Comment: @Joris Meys: that's the exact value i'm getting on windows , but NAs on UNIX :[1] "-3032615078557"
 , is this can be fixed on UNIX ??

Comment: @weblover : which part of "give us reproducible code" do you not understand? How can I know if I can't reproduce what you tell us?

Comment: @Joris Meys : i updated my question , and added 1 formula  that have the problem.

Comment: @weblover : thx. can you add how much is nrow(yi)? I still can't run the code.

Comment: @Joris Meys : N=16569 = nrow(yi) , that's written in the code. for each (ol,oh) the value of A should be saved in a data frame , but that's not the main point now.

Comment: @weblover : I can run the code but still can't reproduce. It works in both Linux and Windows for me.

Comment: @Joris Meys  : what do you mean with you can't reproduce ? and why it's not working for me in Linux(Fedora)

Comment: @weblover : no clue. It works exactly the same in Debian lenny, Ubuntu 10 and Windows7 (all platforms I can use here). No overflows of any kind, and everything is converted to numeric. Tried N <- as.integer(N) as well, but still no change.

Comment: @Joris Meys :  i think there is something wrong , when i try to run the code with only the calculation of A and B(on Unix), everything works ok , but when i add even more variables to test , A become NAs .
i don't know what's happening here