# same operation but different answers(R and C#)

Tags: c#, r

i have an R script that make some calculations.

and i found the same script but in C# , but it's giving me answers different than R.

```
the R code is :

    count=16569
    for(ind1 in seq(1,count,by=1000))
        {
        for(ind2 in seq(1,count,by=1000))
     {

        value=(count*(ind1^2)) + ((count*(count+1)*((2*count)+1))/6) -(2*ind1*((count*(count+1))/2)) + (2*count*ind1*(count-ind2+1)) + ((count-ind2+1)*(count^2)) + (2*count*(ind2-count-1)*(ind2+count))

    }

}
```

and the C# code  is :

```
 double count=16569
        for(int ind1=1;ind1<=count;ind1+=1000)
            {
            for(int ind2=1;ind2<=count;ind2+=1000)
         {

            value=(count*(Math.Pow(ind1,2))) + ((count*(count+1)*((2*count)+1))/6) -(2*ind1*((count*(count+1))/2)) + (2*count*ind1*(count-ind2+1)) + ((count-ind2+1)*(Math.Pow(count,2))) + (2*count*(ind2-count-1)*(ind2+count))

        }

    }
```

> ```
> for the first round , the value in R is : -3032615095125
> but the value in C# is : 4548002182315
> ```

what is the error ?

thanks

Comment: @lselzer : sorry , i changed the R-code , it;s count and not N

Comment: The R code fails to define N. Did you mean `count`?

Comment: @DWin : yes , i already edited my question

Comment: With the R code I get `value` ->  1.209314e+12

Comment: @DWin : for the first loop , the value is : -3032615095125

Comment: @Joris Meys : the value in R is : -3032615095125
but the value in C# is : 4548002182315

Comment: @smack : I know, I see, and I just noticed both the code and the numbers remind me an awful lot about this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042728/nas-produced-by-integer-overflow-r-on-linux/ Be aware of the fact that having two accounts is heavily frowned upon, if that would be the case.

Comment: Joris Meys : that's right , i got the value expression from this question. because i need to test it on a large value.

Comment: @Joris Meys : 2 accounts of what ?? is it forbidden to copy sentences from other question ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know R, but with respect to C#, What datatype is the variable `value`? Could it be that the values are overflowing and therefore junk?

Comment: @Bhargav Bhat : in C# value is double .

Comment: @Smack: Ok. Did you try with decimal instead of double? It has a larger range. You could uses Convert.ToDecimal() to convert from a double to decimal. Also, you could break the assignment into multiple statements and see if you're exceeding the range in one of the intermediate steps.

Comment: @Bhargav Bhat : when changing it to float , i got some errors : canno't use * operator with decimal. because this value is going to be multiplied by other values another place , but the first value is wrong

Comment: @Smack: You could use `Decimal.Multiply()` instead of the * operator. as a bonus, you can check for and deal with `OverflowExceptions` that this method may throw. You can see this link for further info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.multiply.aspx

Comment: @Bhargav Bhat : this will need alot of changing and work to handle the exception , i want an easy method

Comment: @Smack: You could simply clamp the value to `Decimal.MaxValue` or `Decimal.MinValue` in the `catch` block, if this is appropriate for your application. The `Decimal` datatype has a range of `+/-1.0e−28`  to `+/-7.9e+28`. So its unlikely that you'll have to deal with an over/underflow condition. In a prototype/exercise application, you can skip the exception checks if you're sure of not exceeding these limits.

Comment: @Bhargav Bhat : i think my values has a max of 13 number , wich is included in double

Comment: @Bhargav Bhat :  i changed everything to decimal , the difference between them is minimized , but there is still some difference

Comment: @Smack: Perhaps you are loosing precision during one of the intermediate steps in the computation which is getting magnified subsequently and hence the difference in the result. Did you try my other suggestion, viz. breaking the statement into multiple steps and checking if you're exceeding the range in one of the intermediate steps.

Comment: @Bhargav Bhat : i did try this , and the difference between the 2 values is now small

Comment: @Smack: Assuming this is a real-world problem and not an exercise, perhaps you'd have to rethink the solution/opt for a different algo in case you keep hitting the limits of the datatypes. Might I ask the purpose/need for working such large numbers? Can they not be biased suitably before use?

Comment: @Bhargav Bhat : it works now , i changed everything to decimal and it works , thanks

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code, I see that the loops won't make any difference.  The values from the previous iteration of your loop are never stored or accessed, so `value` will always be set by the last run of the loop.

In effect, you just have three constants:   `count = 16569`   `ind1 = 16001`   `ind2 = 16001`

And the answer is 1.209314e+12, whether or not the loops are run.

In C# (once I add semicolons and a variable declaration for `value` so it will run):
1209314008875

So I get the same answer in both R and C#.  I know you asked why the answers are different, but you might look at whether the code is doing what you want in the first place;  I'm not sure why the loops are there.  With the code you've given, you could just plug-in the constants above to verify what your machine is giving you.

Comment: @smack That's really strange.  If you'd like to see your code working, try one of the public RWeb installations, for example: [http://data-engine.tama.ac.jp/Rweb/Rweb.general.html](http://data-engine.tama.ac.jp/Rweb/Rweb.general.html).  Just paste your code in the box--be sure to add `value` to the very end of your script (after the last closing bracket) so that a result will be printed.  It's very bizarre indeed that your system is producing odd values in both R and C#, and I'd be very interested to know the cause once you get it sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

Check the bit sizes of your variables. The value in R looks fishy.

Also, why is count double and not int?

Comment: @Jonathan Henson : they are to big , but why there is difference between the 2 values ?? and N dosen't matter if it's double or int

Comment: @smack If they are too big, then you will have unpredictable results. If your max value is 4294967296 for int, any calculation that evaluates over that will produce sporadic results. Perhaps use long instead?

Comment: @Jonathan Henson : i'm using double for value not int. can't use long because some of the other values are double.

Comment: @smack, whoops!, wrong language, try decimal instead of double.

Comment: @Jonathan Henson : i tried float , but the same value resulted but with . and E+12

Comment: @Jonathan Henson : when changing it to float , i got some errors : canno't use * operator with decimal. because this value is going to be multiplied by other values another place , but the first value is wrong