# Multiplication of large integers

Tags: r, largenumber, integer-arithmetic

I tried to multiply `111111111*111111111`, which is the same as `111111111^2`, and got incorrect results. It should give `12345678987654321`, but instead it gives a rounding error. Do I need to use some special variable type for long numbers or is this a bug with R?

Comment: Searching for `[r] gmp` gives related answers such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042728/nas-produced-by-integer-overflow-r-on-linux , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053397/long-bigint-decimal-equivalent-datatype-in-r

Answer (score 19):

The 'gmp' package will allow you to do operations on values that large though.

```
> library(gmp)
> j <- 111111111
> k <- as.bigz(j)
> mul.bigz(k, k)
[1] "12345678987654321"
```

Answer (score 7):

It's not a limitation of R specifically, it's a limitation of [double precision floating-point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format) arithmetic. A standard double-precision floating-point number has around 16 decimal digits of accuracy. The answer to your sum requires 17. R does not have a variable type with greater precision, but neither do many other languages.

Answer (score 6):

Also, new package [int64](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/int64/index.html) from Romain Francois.