# How to get the exact value of factorial(100)

Tags: r

When I run `factorial(100)` in the console, I get

```
factorial(100)
# [1] 9.332622e+157
```

But I want to see the exact value of `factorial(100)`. How would I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `gmp` library might do what you want.  I have not verified that this is the correct result:

```
> library(gmp)
> j <- as.bigz(100)
> factorial(j)
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000
```

See also [Multiplication of large integers in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175965/multiplication-of-large-integers-in-r)

Comment: [seems right](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/factorial-large-number/) if this is to be trusted